# What does "irreducible polynomial modulo $p$" mean?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am reading a file that says that in the polynomial ring $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, the ideal $(p,f(x))$ where $p $ is a prime number and $f(x)$ is irreducible polynomial modulo $p$, is a prime ideal.

I don't understand the meaning of  "irreducible polynomial modulo $p$". Can someone clarify the words? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Irreducible in the polynomial ring of the field of $p$ elements $\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z[x] = \Bbb F_p[x] = GF(p)[x] =\cdots$.

Comment: I see. Thank you. :-)

Comment: I would say this answer is wrong. The right answer is "irreducible in the ring $\mathbb{Z}_p [x]$".

Comment: @boumol Good point I was just going to say the same thing.  Everything is a unit in $\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$ so factorization there is not very interesting.  Also, please write $\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$ because $\Bbb Z_p$ means the $p$-adic integers.